# How to make functions called from arguments like args.IsNullOrEmpty() instead IsNullOrEmpty(args) in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can make a function with called from arguments

```
def IsNullOrEmpty(strInput):
    #strInput is string type (built-in)
    #doing something
```

above function is call like:

```
IsNullOrEmpty(strInput)
```

How can i make a same function called like this? Without make new class extend from built-in String class

```
strInput.IsNullOrEmpty()
```

Comment: You need to create a class which contains the method IsNullOrEmpty() and the class or the instance needs to be called strInput

Comment: I wanna define few function with string argument. but string class is built-in

Comment: AK47 is right, but why do you even need this? `if strInput:` will suffice, surely as easy as a function/method call. Or if you insist on a method at least use `return not strInput`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I wanna make some function called from arguments. Above function is only sample

Comment: If `strInput` is `None`, you cannot call any method on it. Because it's `None` and doesn't have any methods.

Comment: My question is How to make a Function. Dont care about content of function

Comment: You are confusing functions with methods. `foo.bar()` is not a replacement for arbitrary `bar(foo)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the Python built-in types, although if you are unwary you might find yourself fighting with odd corner-cases. For example:

```
class MyStr(str):
    def is_null_or_empty(self):  # see PEP 8 for naming conventions
        return not bool(self)

str1, str2 = MyStr("non-empty"), MyStr("")
print(str1.is_null_or_empty(), str2.is_null_or_empty())
```

should print

```
False True
```

Note that all methods inherited from the base class (the system `str` type) that return strings will continue to return simple strings rather than `MyStr` instances. To have them return such instances your class needs to wrap each such method. Here's an example for the `upper` method:

```
def upper(self):
    return MyStr(super().upper())
```

Here `super().upper()` is a call to the super-class's (*i,.e.*, `str`'s) `upper` method with `self` as the current instance (and therefore passed to the method as argument one) - it can no longer simply be inherited and referenced from `self`, because the `MyStr` definition of `upper` would be resolved first resulting in an infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks holdenweb. Is there anyway if i dont want to make new Class?

Comment: To non-built-in objects you can add attributes, therefore methods too, from outside (without subclassing them first. But to data types, files and some other instances you cannot. Doing so would result either in AttributeError or TypeError: "Can't set attributes of built-in/extension type '...'"

Comment: As Delen says, to be able to call a function or method on an object it has to be an attribute of the class, and you can't add attributes to most built-in types (functions being an exception, I don't know of there are others)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of adapting a datatype to accept external attributes:

```
class unicode (__builtins__.unicode):
    def __new__ (cls, u=""):
        self = __builtins__.unicode.__new__(cls, u)
        return self

# So, you do it just once and then you can:
def add_check (obj):
    obj.IsNullOrEmpty = lambda: not obj

u1 = unicode("12345")
u2 = unicode()
add_check(u1)
add_check(u2)

print u1.IsNullOrEmpty()
print u2.IsNullOrEmpty()
```

Note: Using:

```
u3 = u'1234'
```

will yield **builtins**.unicode(), not our modified type, so you will have to be explicite.

Comment: And. as with my solution, any system functions that return results of the built-in type will continue to do so even after the `unicode` name is rebound.